# Unable to locate UIATextField in mac machine using Appium

Tags: xcode, appium, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios, java-client

I have the below code in Appium to automate mobile application.

```
MobileElement objelement=null;
wait = new WebDriverWait(mobileDriveriOS, 15);
objelement=(MobileElement)mobileDriveriOS.findElement(By.xpath("UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATextField[1]/UIATextField[1]"));
objelement.sendKeys("Test");
```

Here mobileDriveriOS is an object of type iOS driver.
Instead of 'sendKeys' tried with click also it dint work out.

The error is "**An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters**"

Comment: Worked with https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4706

Answer (score 2):

Your xpath query is missing the first two slashes from search criteria. This should work better:

```
objelement=(MobileElement)mobileDriveriOS.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATextField[1]/UIATextField[1]"));
```